# Deleting document inside a nested Collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I was making a function to clear all documents inside a nested collection. I've accessed it as follow.

```
const deleteChat = async () => {

  const chatSnapShot = await db
    .collection("chats")
    .doc(router.query.id)
    .collection("messages")
    .get();

  chatSnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
};
```

How can I do that? This `doc.data()` returns the data inside the `messages` collection. I've tried using other solutions but things doesn't work. Help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` reads all documents from that collection. You need to use [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete) to delete a document. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const deleteChat = async () => { 
  const chatSnapShot = await db
    .collection("chats")
    .doc(router.query.id)
    .collection("messages")
    .get();

  const deletePromises = chatSnapshot.docs.map(d => d.ref.delete());

  await Promise.all(deletePromises)
  console.log("Documents deleted")
};
```

Here `chatSnapShot.docs` is an array of [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot) and you can get [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) for each doc using `.ref` property. Then the doc reference has `.delete()` method to delete the document. This method returns a promise so you can map an array of promises and run them at once using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

---

You can also delete documents in batches of up to 500 documents using [batched writes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).

Comment: Yep it did worked, thanks. Can you just explain that `d.ref` part and then you did `Promise.all(deletePromises)`